# Apply draft option of graphicx for only one chapter/section

Tags: graphics, draft

I am writing a thesis with many figures in each chapter. It takes quite some time to compile and convert to PDF. If I use the `draft` option of the `graphicx` package the figures will be skipped. This is good, but not for the chapter that I am working on. Is there a way to turn the option on only for other chapters? I know about `\include` and `\includeonly` but I want the whole thesis text to be there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Option `draft` of package `graphicx` can be enabled or disabled later:

```
...
\usepackage{graphicx}
...

\begin{document}
...
\setkeys{Gin}{draft}
\chapter{Chapter with draft}
...
\setkeys{Gin}{draft=false}
...
\end{document}
```